# Access POST values in Symfony 4 Controller with curl

Tags: php, symfony, curl

Good morning.

I'm currently trying to access the POST data from a curl request in a Symfony 4 Controller.

My controller looks like the following:

```
class OrderController extends AbstractController  
{  
/**  
 * @Route("/order", name="order")  
 */  
public function index(Request $request)  
{                                                      
    var_dump($request->request->all());die;       

    return $this->json([                                    
        'message' => 'Welcome to your new controller!',     
        'path' => 'src/Controller/OrderController.php',     
    ]);                                                     
    }                                                           
}
```

When I run `php bin\console server:run` and access the localhost/order in the browser I get the page it is supposed to get. If I curl the url with

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/order
```

I also get the right results. But when I try to send a json body on the curl request, on the above controller I just get an empty array.

My request looks like the following:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '
{'json':{
"id": "1",
"customer-id": "1",
"items": [
  {
    "product-id": "B102",
    "quantity": "10", 
    "unit-price": "4.99",
    "total": "49.90"
  }
],
"total": "49.90"
}}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/order
```

Any idea on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe a typo at the single quotes before json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Request object will only return form parameters via $request->request methods. if you want to access the JSON body, you need to use $request->getContent(). If that content is json, your code will look something like this:

```
$json = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
var_dump($json['json']);
```